# In ConEmu / Cmder, how do you setup ConEmu Here to work with powershell?

Tags: powershell, context-menu, conemu, cmder

I am trying to get the ConeEmu Here context menu item to work everywhere in windows explorer.

Settings -> Integration -> ConEmu Here -> Command

Currently I have:

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoExit -Command Set-Location -LiteralPath '%L'
```

This works when you right-click on a folder name, but if I right-click on the empty-space in an open folder window, I get this:

```
Explorer.EXE  
This file does not have a porgbram associated with it for performing this action
```

Answer (score 3):

Enter this into Settings -> Integration -> ConEmu Here -> Command

```
powershell -cur_console:n
```